# How to make UIKit Slider only go next and not previous

Tags: javascript, jquery, uikit

I have a UIKit Slider that has a navigation button inside each of its 5 slider items. It works fine when you click to go to the 2nd slider up to the 5th slider. But when you click to go to the first slider, it slides back like a "previous" nav behavior instead of "next". It's an infinite slider so I'd like to force it to only navigate from right to left all the time.

My slider looks like this:

```
<div id="slider" class="uk-position-relative uk-visible-toggle uk-light" tabindex="-1" uk-slider>
    <ul class="uk-slider-items uk-grid uk-grid-collapse">
        <li class="uk-width-auto" style="width: 30%">
            <div class="uk-panel">
                <div style="background-image:url('https://getuikit.com/docs/images/photo.jpg'); width: 100%; height: 400px;"></div>
                <div class="uk-position-center uk-text-center">
                    <h2 uk-slider-parallax="x: 100,-100">Heading 1</h2>
                    <p uk-slider-parallax="x: 200,-200">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
                    <button class="uk-button uk-button-secondary slider-button" data-slide-index="0">Show</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <!-- Four more similar slider items here -->
    </ul>
</div>
```

And here's my button navigation script (I use a custom button because I have other functions for it):

```
$(".slider-button").click(function() {
    var slideIndex = $(this).data("slide-index");
    UIkit.slider("#slider").show(slideIndex);
});
```

[Here's a codepen](https://codepen.io/jonacornejo/pen/RwevQEv) to demo it better.

Answer (score 0):

Oop nevermind, I just figured it out. I had to check if the target slide index is greater than the current slide index, and use "next" instead of calling its index. I changed my script to this:

```
$(".slider-button").click(function() {
    
    var slideIndex = $(this).data("slide-index");

    var slider = UIkit.slider("#slider");

    if ( slideIndex > slider.index ) {
        slider.show(slideIndex); // Show the desired slide
    } else {
        slider.show('next'); // Move to the next slide
    }
});
```